# How can I check if a file exists and serve it, otherwise become reverse proxy in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

This is my requirement. I want to create a BLOB service that serves images, videos, audios, and other files.

Client sends a request for a given file:

```
https://blob.example.com/blogPost/background.webp
```

Nginx should check if this file exists on the hard drive, serve it if it exists.
Otherwise it should act as a reverse proxy and guide the request to an upstream application that would serve the image.

That upstream application then asynchronously download the image from the original cloud and save it on the hard for future requests.

This is my Nginx config file:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server
{
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size 0;

    ssl_certificate /Project/SiteQwik/Certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /Project/SiteQwik/Key.pem;

    error_page 502 /502.html;

    location /502
    {
        root /Base/Infra/Nginx;
        internal;
    }

    location /
    {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:56710;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    
    location ~ ^/(fa|en|ar|ru|tr)(/|$) {
        rewrite ^/(fa|en|ar|ru|tr)/(.*)$ /$2?locale=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/(fa|en|ar|ru|tr)$ /?locale=$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:56710;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to implement that requirement in this file.

Comment: see serverfault.com: [nginx serving alternate location on 404](https://serverfault.com/questions/537634/nginx-serving-alternate-location-on-404)

Comment: @Luuk, thank you for the link. It seems that it could be the answer. Could you post it as an answer (in an abstract way) so that I can accept it and it could be a good reference for future users. Thanks again.

Comment: Please tak a look at: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)